# Im trying to deploy my ml model which classifies plant images, but im getting file not found error even though its path is correct

Tags: python, flask, keras, conv-neural-network, web-deployment

the error is [cmd error snip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7JmD.png)
the above picture shows the error im facing in cmd

**the file directory**

```
templates
--->index.html   
uploads  
venv  
app.py  
cnn_model.pkl  
index.py  
main.py
```

---

**app.py**

```
    from flask import Flask

    UPLOAD_FOLDER = "/uploads"

    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.secret_key = "secret key"
    app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
```

**index.py**

```
    from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, flash, url_for
    import main
    import urllib.request
    from app import app
    from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
    from main import getPrediction
    import os


    @app.route('/')
    def index():
        return render_template('index.html')


    @app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
    def submit_file():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            if 'file' not in request.files:
                flash('No file part')
                return redirect(request.url)
            file = request.files['file']
            if file.filename == '':
                flash('No file selected for uploading')
                return redirect(request.url)
            if file:
                filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
                print(filename)
                file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],filename))
                label = getPrediction(filename)
                flash(label)
                return redirect('/')


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run()
```

**index.html**

```
    <!doctype html>
    <title>Plant Classifier</title>
    <h2>Select a file to upload</h2>
    <p>
        {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
          {% if messages %}
            Label: {{ messages[0] }}

          {% endif %}
        {% endwith %}
    </p>
    <form method="post" action="/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <dl>
        <p>
            <input type="file" name="file" autocomplete="off" required>
        </p>
        </dl>
        <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </p>
    </form>
```

**main.py**

```
    labels=['Pepper__bell___Bacterial_spot','Pepper__bell___healthy',
    'Potato___Early_blight','Potato___Late_blight','Potato___healthy',
    'Tomato_Bacterial_spot','Tomato_Early_blight','Tomato_Late_blight',
    'Tomato_Leaf_Mold','Tomato_Septoria_leaf_spot',
    'Tomato_Spider_mites_Two_spotted_spider_mite','Tomato__Target_Spot',
    'Tomato__Tomato_YellowLeaf__Curl_Virus','Tomato__Tomato_mosaic_virus',
    'Tomato_healthy']

    def convert_image_to_array(image_dir):
        try:
            image = cv2.imread(image_dir)
            if image is not None :
                image = cv2.resize(image, default_image_size)   
                return img_to_array(image)
            else :
                return np.array([])
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error : {e}")
            return None

    default_image_size = tuple((256, 256))


    def getPrediction(filename):
        file_object = 'cnn_model.pkl'
        model=pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb'))

        #model = pickle.load(file_object)
        #imgpath='/content/drive/My Drive/Final Project files/TEST.JPG'
        lb = preprocessing.LabelBinarizer()

        imar = convert_image_to_array(filename) 
        npimagelist = np.array([imar], dtype=np.float16)/225.0 
        PREDICTEDCLASSES2 = model.predict_classes(npimagelist) 
        num=np.asscalar(np.array([PREDICTEDCLASSES2]))
        return labels[num]
```

firstly i upload a pic through html file and this uploaded file is passed down to my saved cnn model which will be used to predict the plant disease and this will be displayed as output.

> https://medium.com/@arifulislam_ron/flask-web-application-to-classify-image-using-vgg16-d9c46f29c4cd
>   im referencing the code from above link

Comment: Nope. Try again. **The path is incorrect and/or there is no file at said path**. Now, with that mis-assumption set aside, follow out WHY it’s NOT correct. (Include the error message as text in the question..)

Comment: i uploaded the error image at the beginning of question once check it

Comment: *..include..as text..*

Comment: https://pastebin.pl/view/29a8185d check the link for error message

Answer (score 1):

Either add like this :

```
import os

basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
UPLOAD_FOLDER = os.path.join(basedir, '/uploads')
```

or

```
UPLOAD_FOLDER = os.getcwd() + '/uploads'
```

Comment: have you checked the path now.?

Comment: yea, the problem is the image which is uploaded is saved on the disk but cant understand why itsshowing error